# Почему кнопка не центрируется по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание

Есть кнопка, которой задаю `css` свойства:

```
vertical-align: middle; 
display: table-cell;
```

а родителю в свою очередь:

```
display: table; 
height: 114px;
```

но кнопка не выравнивается по вертикали - почему? Как исправить?

```css
.button-wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 114px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-theme-primary {
  background-color: #9A1E41;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="btn-theme-primary">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить еще один контейнер, к которому и нужно применить `display:table-cell` и `vertical-align:middle;`:

```css
.button-wrapper {
  display: table;
  height: 114px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.button-wrapper-inner {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

.btn-theme-primary {
  background-color: #9A1E41;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <div class="button-wrapper-inner">
    <button class="btn-theme-primary">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

А вообще, можно обойтись и без `display:table`:

```css
.button-wrapper {
  height: 114px;
  line-height: 114px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-theme-primary {
  background-color: #9A1E41;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="btn-theme-primary">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

А можно вообще использовать flexbox, тогда можно и убрать `vertical-align` (это свойство для детей flex-контейнера игнорируется), и убрать `display: table-cell` (это свойство ничего не поменяет, так как дети flex-контейнера становятся неявно чем-то вроде `inline-block`). Демонстрация:

```css
.button-wrapper {
  /* Делаем флекс-контейнером */
  display: flex;
  /* Выравниваем элементы по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Выравниваем элементы по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  height: 114px;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-theme-primary {
  background-color: #9A1E41;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="btn-theme-primary">ДОБАВИТЬ</button>
</div>
```

Comment: можно, но мы живет в постсоветском лагере, где очень много простого люда, которые сидят на  `windows 7` и `ie9-10`, а терять этих посетителей оч как не хочется..)

Comment: @Вася Ну вообще сам IE настойчиво просит обновится, и в обновлениях винды IE11 ставится одним из первых. И flexbox работает в IE10. По идее поэтому можно уже потихоньку убирать поддержку IE9.

Comment: @Вася Немного обновил ответ.